# Retrieving message body with Gmail API

Tags: go, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the Gmail API to extract the bodies of emails, although I'm unable to actually retrieve the bodies of the emails, as all I get is the following:

```html
<div dir="lt
<!DOCTYPE ht
```

I've written the following to collect the bodies of the emails:

```golang
messages, err := srv.Users.Messages.List(user).Do()

for _, l := range messages.Messages {

    m, err := srv.Users.Messages.Get(user, l.Id).Do()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve labels: %v", err)
    }
    for _, part := range m.Payload.Parts {
        if part.MimeType == "text/html" {
            data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(part.Body.Data)
            html := string(data)
            fmt.Println(html)
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any ideas on how I can get the actual body of the email?

Comment: `DecodeString` has an error return; *never* ignore errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the error returned for `DecodeString`, but otherwise you should try using `base64.URLEncoding` instead of `base64.StdEncoding` to decode the data.

From the documentation on [`MessagePartBody`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1#MessagePartBody.Data):

```golang
    // Data: The body data of a MIME message part as a base64url encoded
    // string. May be empty for MIME container types that have no message
    // body or when the body data is sent as a separate attachment. An
    // attachment ID is present if the body data is contained in a separate
    // attachment.
    Data string `json:"data,omitempty"`
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I used `base64.URLEncoding` and now it returns all of the html associated with it.